# Strange behavior of Jasmine test with CoffeeScript codes

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I am writing Jasmine test but it shows strange behavior.

This is my code:

```
root = exports ? this
class root.SomeClass
  constructor: ->
    @index = 0
  incrementIndex: -> @index++
  decrementIndex: -> @index--
```

And this is my test code:

```
describe "Object", ->
  object = new SomeClass

  describe ".index", ->
    describe "when index = 3", ->
      object.index = 3

      describe "when next button is clicked", ->
        object.incrementIndex()
        it "returns 4", ->
          expect(object.index).toBe 4

      describe "when previous button is clicked", ->
        object.decrementIndex()
        it "returns 3", ->
          expect(object.index).toBe 2
```

The test result is below:

```
Failing 2 specs

Photos initialized .index when index = 3 when next button is clicked returns 4.
Expected 3 to be 4.

Photos initialized .index when index = 3 when previous button is clicked returns 3.
Expected 3 to be 2.
```

And it is strange that **when I comment out the last 4 lines of test code, the test pass.** I could not understand what is happening... >_<

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are your `describe` and `it` callbacks happening in the order you think they are? What happens if you put two `object.decrementIndex()` calls in "previous button" test?

Comment: The message `Failing 1 spec Photos initialized .index when index = 3 when next button is clicked returns 4.
Expected 2 to be 4.` has returned. I suppose the value of `object.index` is saved between two tests. I am going to try `beforeEach` now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tests interact which each other.  [Do setup in `beforeEach` blocks](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Setup_and_Teardown).

```coffeescript
describe "Object", ->
  object = undefined

  beforeEach ->
    object = new SomeClass

  describe ".index", ->
    describe "when index = 3", ->
      beforeEach ->
        object.index = 3

      describe "when next button is clicked", ->
        beforeEach ->
          object.incrementIndex()

        it "returns 4", ->
          expect(object.index).toBe 4

      describe "when previous button is clicked", ->
        beforeEach ->
          object.decrementIndex()

        it "returns 3", ->
          expect(object.index).toBe 2
```

Not checked if this piece of code is valid, but still shows how you should fix your tests.  Note `object = undefined` in the 2 line.  You need to declare variable here, otherwise `object` will be local to each `beforeEach` and `it` block.

Comment: Thank you skalee, my code works with your advice. I was not accustomed to use `beforeEach` but it reveals to be very important.

Comment: @weed: `beforeEach` is executed before each test.  Putting some code directly in `describe` block will make it executed 1) once and 2) before tests are defined (that is, before all `beforeEach` blocks, even those defined in outer describe blocks).  It's generally undesirable.